# No [login] credential was passed - Laravel & Sentinel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sentinel, cartalyst-sentinel

I have started a new project with Laravel, and after I included Sentinel and tried to register a new user, it keeps showing me this message: `No [login] credential was passed`. What Login credentials, I'm **registering** new user?? I'm using the latest version of Laravel 5.5, and latest of Sentinel as well. For registering, I'm using `registerAndActivate()` method provided in Sentinel documentation.

This is not my first time using Sentinel, but this is the first time I see this message and I have no idea what is going on?

I'm using `Homestead` as the host system. First migration has passed, everything with DB is okay.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Still, don't work, but I know where is the problem. It's the function `validateUser` from `IlluminateUserRepository.php` Sentinel's file. I have no idea what's going on...

MAYBE:
New Laravel 5.5, and the Sentinel hasn't released new version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me when I changed the 'email' column into 'username', but when I used the default column names, it worked properly.

Comment: I made an error somewhere in the process of changing the `email` field into `username`. It worked properly when I did it all over again.